# Proper way to use Chrome local storage Get

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm making a Chrome extension and am wondering what's the best way to use Chrome's asynchronous local storage `get`. I want to use a number in the user's storage to return the right picture to be displayed. I have this function that sets the `window`'s `sheetURL` property to the correct URL of the picture:

```
var getCurSheet = function(){
   chrome.storage.local.get('sheet', function(data){
      $.isEmptyObject(data) ? sheetNum = 1 : sheetNum = data[0];
      switch (sheetNum) {
         case 1:
            window.sheetURL = 'http://i.imgur.com/QlTafAU.png';    
         case 2:
            window.sheetURL = 'http://i.imgur.com/jLGpcKz.png';
         case 3:
            window.sheetURL = 'http://i.imgur.com/2uAyumP.png';
         default:
            window.sheetURL = 'http://static.koalabeast.com/images/flair.png';
      }
   });
}
```

This gets called before I set an `<img>`'s source to be the link stored in `window.sheetURL`:

```
var flairs = document.createElement('img');
getCurSheet();
$(flairs).attr({
   'src':window.sheetURL,
   'id':'flairs'
});
```

Although this works, I get the feeling that this isn't the best solution to deal with asynchronous calls. Is there a better way of handling this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Untested, but try this refactoring:

```
function getCurSheet () {
   var sheetUrls = {
      1: 'http://i.imgur.com/QlTafAU.png',
      2: 'http://i.imgur.com/jLGpcKz.png',
      3: 'http://i.imgur.com/2uAyumP.png'
   };
   var defaultSheetUrl = 'http://static.koalabeast.com/images/flair.png';
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      chrome.storage.local.get('sheet', function(data) {
         resolve(sheetUrls[data] || defaultSheetUrl);
      });
   });
}

getCurSheet().then(function (url) {
   $('<img>').attr({
      src: url,
      id: 'flairs'
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for making an intimidating topic look simple. I'll try that out.